# Edit Django User admin template

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

I need to edit the template shown for editing a specific user. I need to display some additional data that doesn't fit in with an include-style.

I apologise for the short question... but that's pretty much all there is at the moment.

Comment: What do you mean "doesnt fit in"? Doesnt display?

Comment: I mean it's not form-data - it's report data. I want to show some user activity from other models *on* the User page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can't accomplish what you want with just subclassing `admin.ModelAdmin`, you can create a directory "admin/auth" in your template directory and put a "change_form.html" in there. In this template you can override blocks that are available e.g. `{% block after_related_objects %}`.

Have a look at `django/contrib/templates/admin/change_form.html` to see how they do stuff, e.g.:

```
{% block extrahead %}{{ block.super }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../jsi18n/"></script>
{{ media }}
{% endblock %}
```

appending stuff to the `extrahead` block.

Comment: you probably need to add it in TEMPLATE_DIR/admin/auth/user if it's only specific to a certain user ;)

Comment: Top stuff. For bonus points, any idea how to get the current user? Ie the object that is being processed.

Comment: {{ original }} is the object being edited. For instance, {{ original.id }}

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at

`django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/auth/user/`

This *should* contain a couple of templates for modifying the users.

You can override these by copying them to `TEMPLATE_DIR/admin/auth` and then changing them.

Also, have a look @ `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html`

This is the file you'd copy and change (to `TEMPLATE_DIR/admin/auth/user/`) to override the change form for that model.

Answer (score 0):

I'd override the admin/auth/user/change_form.html template and add a custom template tag to handle whatever queries need to be done to fetch the data you need to display.